# Can't find only one word using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to "find" a very specific series of characters in java, but my regular expression is not working properly.

I want to find a word (any word), then a space, then a forwardslash, then another space, then an 'M' (lower or upper case), then a series of digits. I'm using the following line:

```
Elements rating = doc.getElementsMatchingText(Pattern.compile("\\b\\s/\\s[mM][0-9]+"));
```

But this is finding whole lines (words before and after the intended pattern). This also doesn't help:

```
Elements rating = doc.getElementsMatchingText(Pattern.compile("^\\b\\s/\\s[mM][0-9]+"));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to get from the pattern you supply? You don't have any capturing groups, so you can only check whether the pattern is found in some text, not extract particular data from the resulting Matcher.

Comment: Don’t post ddoouubbllee--eessccaappeedd Java. Post your expected inputs and your expected results, and what patterns you are using.

Answer (score 2):

The correct pattern for your case is `\\b\\w+\\s/\\s[mM][0-9]+`.

However, the problem you describe is related to the API you use rather than to the pattern.
Note that `getElementsMatchingText` doesn't allow you to access match details, therefore you cannot extract part of the text that matched the pattern.

You need to iterate over all elements of the `doc` manually and apply `Matcher.find()` to the text of each element, or simply apply `Matcher.find()` with the same pattern again to the text of elements returned by `getElementsMatchingText`. Then you would be able to extract the matched part as `Matcher.group()`.

Comment: I don’t think the pattern looks correct; for example, the `\b\s` will only match an ASCII whitespace that follows a Unicode word character.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is flawed. I would propose

```
\w+ / [Mm]\d+
```

(remember to escape appropriately when you put in a java string)

A few things about your regex:

1) You don't have anything to currently match the "word (any word)" (!!!) I chose \w+ to match words only with at least one word character. You can do something like \w{2,10} to do words between 2 and 10 characters, for example, if you want to further customize.

2) You don't need the \b at all since the \w* match only matches valid word characters

3) keep in mind \s may match more than just a space.. I use just a space but you can put in \s if you are ok with it matching tab, new line (if configured that way), etc.

4) I think \d is more idiomatic and readable than [0-9]

Comment: This makes no sense. The so-called noncapturing group is utterly immaterial.

Comment: @tchrist -- doh, you're right about the \b expression. Probably should have started from scratch and clear mind instead of with tweaking expression in question :). Will edit, thanks!

Comment: As for your point 2, there is indeed a subtle difference between `\b\w+\b` and `\w+`: the former requires boundaries at both sides, where the latter does not, and so could under complex extenuating circumstances match the interior of a string like `"peek"`, like just the double-e. The former could not. However, Java’s `\b` and `\w` (and `\s` etc) are **completely broken** with respect to one another unless you use the new-in-Java-7 `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` or embedded `(?U)` pattern-compilation flag.

Answer (score -1):

About the regex, try with:

> .* \ [Mm][1-9]*

I used http://rubular.com/ to test my regex, so you can make your experiment.

Bye

Comment: Why in the world would someone use Ruby to test a Java pattern?

Comment: First of all because it was the first regex tester I found :P I thought that regex in java and ruby, at basic level, was the same.

Comment: I adapt my regex for java .* \\ [Mm][1-9]*.*, it seems work but it find the whole line. I'm not an expert so sorry for my answer